# Subclass "is" class confuses me

Tags: objective-c, oop

I'm studying up on archiving data, and I realize the standard collection classes provide easy archival, however I want to archive an `NSMutableArray`. So I read that since `NSMutableArray` "is a" `NSArray` because it is a subclass, then this is fine.

But that idea stumps me, and I realize this is a basic concept of Objective-C so I want to make sure I get it right.

Suppose you have a class "automobile" with a subclass "jeep."  Now based on the above, you can say this:

`automobileInstance=jeepInstance;`

...because a jeep is a subclass of automobile.

But this seems backwards to me. I would think you should instead say that a subclass instance can be equal to its superclass instance:

jeep = auto

Because after all a jeep "is a" automobile, but not all automobiles are jeeps.

So why then can you do this:

`NSArray*newArray=nsmutableArrayInstance;`

It's the same idea as saying:

`automobile=jeep;` in my example.

Your subclass might have added many new instance variables, for example, but if you set it equal to a superclass, those iVars are "lost" or at least the super class doesn't recognize them, so it isn't truly capturing the object, it would seem.

Going the other way, saying the `sublass instance = superclass instance` makes sense, since everything in the superclass is in the subclass; you just don't get values for the extra iVars that are in the subclass but not in the superclass, they might be set to default zero, but at least they exist.

Comment: Objective-C doesn't follow sentence structure of the English language.

Comment: Consider that you have a parking spot for Automobiles.  A Jeep can go there, cause a Jeep is an Automobile.  But if you had a parking spot specifically for Jeeps, you couldn't just stick any old random Automobile in it, could you?  It might not be a Jeep.  Now consider that `Automobile * auto` declares a place to put Automobiles (technically, pointers to Automobiles, but eh).  A parking spot, if you will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it this way:  all jeeps are automobiles.  Not all automobiles are jeeps.  So you can say:

Automobile a = jeepInstance;  // A jeep is always an automobile

But not:

Jeep j = autoInstance; // fails - autoInstance might be a Mazda, instead.

Answer (score 1):

A superclass pointer can point to an object allocated from the subclass, since the class members of the superclass are always present in the subclass.

```
 autoMobilePointer = jeepObject; // works
```

This isn't true the other way around, since the subclass has members that are not present in the superclass.

```
 jeepPointer = autoMobileObject; // doesn't work
```

Comment: essentially then, in your first example, your new auto pointer loses any members in jeep

Comment: effectively so, it can't access them through autoMobilePointer. I'm pretty sure if you cast that pointer to a jeepPointer then you could - the jeepObject is what you allocated in memory after all.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem here is that you're confusing assignment and equality, and maybe classes and objects, too. Remember that `=` means assignment, whereas `==` and `-isEqual` are tests for equality. If B is a subclass of A, then every B *is an* A, just as every Jeep *is an* automobile, and every human *is a* mammal.

But when you say:

```
automobile = jeep;
```

what you're doing is *assigning* the value of `jeep` to the variable `automobile`. You're *not* saying that every automobile in the world is a Jeep, you're saying that the specific variable `automobile` refers to a specific instance of Jeep. It's exactly as if I asked you:

> What car do you drive?

In my head, I'm expecting you to reply with information about some car. You could say that the memory location in my head that I've reserved for your answer has type `Automobile*`, since it could refer to any car. You reply:

> I drive that red Jeep parked near the tree.

It might help to choose more descriptive names for your variables. Use something specific, like:

```
Automobile *theCarThatAndrewxDrives = jeep;
```

This makes it obvious that we're talking about one specific car, not all cars.